# Method wont work when I create an object

Tags: java, date, methods

I am building a Date class and when I try to create an object with it doesn't work. (errors in daysPerMonth)
However when I use setNewDay method outside of the object it does work.

Do you guys have any clues on what i'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public class Date{

    private Dag day;
    private Maand month;
    private Jaar year;
    private int maxday;

    public Date(int day, int month, int year){
        setDate(day, month, year);
    }


    public void setDate(int day, int month, int year){
        this.month = new Maand(month);
        setNewDay(day);
        this.year = new Jaar(year);
    }


    private void daysPerMonth(){
        int february;
        if(year.getYear()%4 == 0) {
            february = 29;
        }else{
            february = 28;
        };
        int[] daymonth={31,february,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30};
        maxday = daymonth[month.getMonth() -1]; 

    }

        public void setNewDay(int day){
        daysPerMonth();
        if(day > 0 && day <= maxday){
            this.day = new Dag(day);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong day");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What indication do you have that there's a problem?

Comment: In particular, more details than "errors in daysPerMonth".

Comment: You're probably getting nullpointers everywhere from this code.

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem in the order of initialization :

```
public void setDate(int day, int month, int year){
    this.month = new Maand(month);
    setNewDay(day); // this method depends indirectly on this.year, which is not yet 
                    // initialized (setNewDay calls daysPerMonth which calls 
                    // year.getYear())
    this.year = new Jaar(year);
}
```

Change it to :

```
public void setDate(int day, int month, int year){
    this.year = new Jaar(year);
    this.month = new Maand(month);
    setNewDay(day);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the order of your calls, this

```
public void setDate(int day, int month, int year){
  this.month = new Maand(month);
  setNewDay(day);
  this.year = new Jaar(year);
}
```

Should be

```
public void setDate(int day, int month, int year){
  this.month = new Maand(month);
  this.year = new Jaar(year);
  setNewDay(day);
}
```

Because `setNewDay()` calls `daysPerMonth()` and that needs the year (`Jaar`).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what year you try.
From memory you need three conditions to get February right: Isnot mod 100 & is mod 400

Comment: and your daymonth is wrong Apr,Jun,Sep,Nov=30, not alternates.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling the `setNewDay()` method before initialising the year ( which is by **default null** ).
 And `setNewDay()` method is instead calling the `daysPerMonth()` method which uses year but since year is currently null( which is by default value for every reference) You are getting **NullPointerException**
So you just need to initialise the year before calling the method `setNewDay()` :

```
public void setDate(int day, int month, int year){
        this.month = new Maand(month);
        this.year = new Jaar(year);
        setNewDay(day);   //call this method after setting up the year
    }
```

So that when you call **`daysPerMonth()`** method your year contains valid data :

```
private void daysPerMonth(){
        int february;
        if(year.getYear()%4 == 0) {  //now year is valid
            february = 29;
        }else{
            february = 28;
        }
        int[] daymonth={31,february,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30};
        maxday = daymonth[month.getMonth() -1]; 

    }
```